# Configure UItabBar from view

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

Hi guys i am having trouble to find out a solution from this problem so i am posting it.
So basically in ipod application we can configure the tabbar items from the application and drag them to change and customize it for ourself.

Does anybody know how to do it?

see the attached image please, thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You really don't have to do anything more. That feature is automatically available when you add 6 or more tabs to the tab bar controller.

`UITabBarController` has a [`customizableViewControllers`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITabBarController/customizableViewControllers) property which is an array of all customizable view controllers. This is set to the `viewControllers` property so all view controllers can be customized by default. If you intend to limit it then set this property appropriately.