# How to set tab-bar image

Tags: ios4, uitabbarcontroller

I have a tab bar in my application and that how I am customizing it

```
home_view_controleller * home_controller =  [[[home_view_controleller alloc]init] autorelease];
NSArray *viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:home_controller, detailController2, detailController3,detailController4,detailController5,nil];
[tabBarController1 setViewControllers:viewControllers animated:YES];
```

as `home_controller` extend `UIViewController`. How I can set its `tabBarItem.image` before adding it to `viewControllers` array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the view controller's [`tabBarItem`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/tabBarItem).

```
home_controller.tabBarItem = [[[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:myTitle image:myImage tag:myTag] autorelease];
```

Comment: hey deepak any expertise on this question?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6572954/configure-uitabbar-from-view/6573033#6573033